# Possible to separate dependency tracking from behavior in knockout js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my current project we had a notional model with many observables and observable arrays in one viewModel along with behavior for modifying the data. Later in the project we wanted to split up the information that was on one "screen" into two screens. This led to how to split up the viewModel so each screen only handled the behavior on it's data. Eventually this was found to be too difficult to split up and we bound the same viewModel to two "screen's".

I wondered if there was a way to have a separate "model" object store the observable's/observable array's allowing you to have the dependency tracking. This way you could share this model object around that encompasses the data and dependency tracking. After that have viewModel's for each screen to encompass behavior, specific to that screen?

I know I could have a separate model object containing observable's and use "with" to bind that model inside the two viewModel's but I wondered if there was another way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.

From Knockout Version 3.2.0 onwards you can use "Knockout Web Components"

Lets imagine you want to make a "Badge", something like this

```
<div class="badge">
  <h1>Name: <span>Joe Blogs</span></h1>
  <h3>Position: <span>Engineer</span></h3>
</div>
```

Now, let's look at this from a re-usable point of view.

The bits you might want to change dynamically are the *name* and the *position*

if you have these already working in Knockout, you might have something like the following:

```
<div id="thebadge" class="badge">
  <h1>Name: <span data-bind="text: name">xxx</span></h1>
  <h3>Position: <span data-bind="text: position">xxx</span></h3>
</div>
```

And then you might actually use it with Knockout, something like the following:

var BadgeViewModel = {
    name: ko.observable('Joe Blogs'),
    position: ko.observable('engineer')
};

Which you then apply to your html using something like the following:

```
ko.applyBindings(BadgeViewModel);
```

***note: I'm just doing things simply here to demonstrate the concept***

So far, so good... that's the classic way of doing things, and if you have that, it's not at all difficult to convert it into a component.

You simply just have to combine your view model, and your html template into a single entity.

so for our example here, we might use:

```
ko.components.register("my-badge", {
  viewModel: function(data) {
    this.name = (data && data.name) || "Not Defined";
    this.position = (data && data.position) || "Not Defined";
  },
  template: '<div id="thebadge" class="badge"><h1>Name: <span data-bind="text: name">xxx</span></h1><h3>Position: <span data-bind="text: position">xxx</span></h3></div>'
});
```

Once you register your component, you can then just use it's registered name in your html mark up as follows:

```
<my-badge></my-badge>
```

And your badge will appear.

The problem is however, your not initializing any data.

If you look at the VM in the second example code, you'll see we have a 'data' object passed to our model, and that we examine that to see if it, and our *name* and *position* properties exist.

If they don't we make them equal "Not Defined"

To pass your parameters in, you simply use the params attribute as follows:

```
<my-badge params="name: 'Joe Blogs', position: 'engineer'"></my-badge>
```

and that will make properties called *name* and *position* available to the component.

Re-using it is easy, just repeat the mark up, eg:

```
<my-badge params="name: 'Joe Blogs', position: 'Engineer'"></my-badge>
<my-badge params="name: 'Fred Blogs', position: 'Scientist'"></my-badge>
<my-badge params="name: 'Andrew Blogs', position: 'Developer'"></my-badge>
<my-badge params="name: 'Tony Blogs', position: 'Manager'"></my-badge>
```

There are MUCH better ways, and if you read the components documentation on the knockout JS website, they recommend that you use requirejs or some other module loader to help you load html chunks only as you need them.

Just using them once or twice however to provide re-usable views, is easy enough if you keep them in seperate .js files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as this part, "I wondered if there was a way to have a separate "model" object store the observable's/observable array's allowing you to have the dependency tracking." Would it be possible to pass in a full model object instead of data to the viewModel. Like var model = function(name, position) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.position = ko.observable(position);
  }; Passing this model to your viewModel that way multiple viewModel's each in there own component could share the same data along with its dependency tracking.

Comment: @RandyHanak not sure to be honest, I've not tried it, but if it's modularity your after Google for "Steve Sanderson Knockout Components Video" it's on vimeo somewhere and he shows you how to carve your components up for reuse in single page applications.